# How to work with unsaved many-to-many relations in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a couple of models in django which are connected many-to-many. I want to create instances of these models *in memory*, present them to the user (via custom method-calls inside the view-templates) and if the user is satisfied, save them to the database.

However, if I try to do anything on the model-instances (call rendering methods, e.g.), I get an error message that says that I have to save the instances first. The documentation says that this is because the models are in a many-to-many relationship.

How do I present objects to the user and allowing him/her to save or discard them without cluttering my database?

(I guess I could turn off transactions-handling and do them myself throughout the whole project, but this sounds like a potentially error-prone measure...)

Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that using django forms may be the answer, as outlined in [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) documentation (search for m2m...).

Edited to add some explanation for other people who might have the same problem:

say you have a model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

class Bar(models.Model):
      foos = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return " ".join([x.name for x in foos])
```

then you cannot call unicode() on an unsaved Bar object. If you do want to print things out before they will be saved, you have to do this:

```
class BarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar

def example():      
    f1 = Foo(name = 'sue')
    f1.save()
    f2 = foo(name = 'wendy')
    f2.save()
    bf = BarForm({'foos' : [f1.id, f2.id]})
    b = bf.save(commit = false)
    # unfortunately, unicode(b) doesn't work before it is saved properly,
    # so we need to do it this way: 
    if(not bf.is_valid()):
        print bf.errors
    else:
        for (key, value) in bf.cleaned_data.items():
            print key + " => " + str(value)
```

So, in this case, you have to have saved Foo objects (which you might validate before saving those, using their own form), and before saving the models with many to many keys, you can validate those as well. All without the need to save data too early and mess up the database or dealing with transactions...

Answer (score 6):

I would add a field which indicates whether the objects are "draft" or "live".  That way they are persisted across requests, sessions, etc. and django stops complaining.

You can then filter your objects to only show "live" objects in public views and only show "draft" objects to the user that created them. This can also be extended to allow "archived" objects (or any other state that makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer, but wagtail's team has made a separate Django extension called [django-modelcluster](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster). It's what powers their CMS's draft previews.

It allows you to do something like this (from their README):

```
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey

class Band(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BandMember(models.Model):
    band = ParentalKey('Band', related_name='members')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then the models can be used like so:

```
beatles = Band(name='The Beatles')
beatles.members = [
    BandMember(name='John Lennon'),
    BandMember(name='Paul McCartney'),
]
```

Here, `ParentalKey` is the replacement for Django's `ForeignKey`. Similarly, they have `ParentalManyToManyField` to replace Django's `ManyToManyField`.