# Work with instance in session before save in database

Tags: python, mysql, django, session, many-to-many

I have a system with several steps. Each step increments one single object instance.
I want to save the instance in db only in the final step, on others just update the instance I saved in the session.

My model class seems like this:

```
class Proposta(models.Model):
    Modelo = models.ForeignKey("ModeloVersao", verbose_name="Modelo")
    Pacotes = models.ManyToManyField("PacoteModelo", null=True, blank=True)
    Opcionais = models.ManyToManyField("ItemModelo", null=True, blank=True)
    RevestimentoInterno = models.ForeignKey("RevestimentoInternoModelo", verbose_name="Revestimento Interno")
    Cor = models.ForeignKey("CorModelo")
    CorSecundaria = models.ForeignKey("CorModeloSecundaria", verbose_name="Cor secundária", null=True, blank=True)
    Data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    Status = models.CharField("Status", choices=STATUS_PROPOSTA, max_length=10)
    Cliente = models.ForeignKey("Cliente")
```

Here's my problem:
When I try to add or retrieve m2m fields it obviously throws a ValueError with the message *'Proposta' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.*

I successfully got the wanted result by creating my obj instance with pk=0 but I'm sure it isn't the best way, if there is.

Do exist a way of doing that without cheating like this.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518162/how-to-work-with-unsaved-many-to-many-relations-in-django) helpful.

Summary for quick reference:

- [Use ModelForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518162/how-to-work-with-unsaved-many-to-many-relations-in-django/519483#519483) - Based on the [ModelForms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)
- [Save it to DB, but use a status field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518162/how-to-work-with-unsaved-many-to-many-relations-in-django/518290#518290) - I think this is less than ideal

I might add that the documentation specifically explains how to deal with M2M fields, in the section that explains [The `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).

Of those, I recommend using ModelForms. Hopefully this helps!